# Getting ReferenceError for own date method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm using Mozilla Firefox 43.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I wrote the following JavaScript method saved in `mainScript.js`:

```
function writeDateHu() {
    var days = ["Hétfő", "Kedd", "Szerda", "Csütörtök", "Péntek", "Szombat", "Vasárnap"];
    var current = new Date();
    var s = "";
    s.concat("<p>", current.getFullYear(), ". ", (current.getMonth() + 1), ". ", current.getDate(), ".<br />", days[current.getDay()], "</p>");
    document.getElementById("datum").innerHTML = s;
}
```

I've also tried to add them by using + instead of `concat`.

In the `main.html` I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HomePage</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainStyle.css" />
        <script type="text/css" src="mainScript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="writeDateHu();">
        <div class="alap">
            <div class="fejlec">
            </div>
            <div class="bal" id="datum">
            </div>
            <div class="tartalom">
            </div>
            <div class="lablec">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

After loading page, the inspector says me `ReferenceError: writeDateHu is not defined`. Also, sometimes (e.g. I insert the script in the html) I don't get the error, but nor the date.

Thanks for any advance.

Comment: Either your script isn't being loaded successfully or else the declaration of the function is not exactly what's posted here. Are any other errors reported? Have you verified that you can load the script at the implicit URL?

Comment: Also that line with `s.concat()` won't do what you think it will; the value of `s` won't be changed.

Comment: strings are immutable `concat()` won't add a string to `s`

Comment: @Pointy I tried. Does not work.

Comment: @Pointy Does it work with plus operator?

Comment: Yes, `s = s + ...` will work.

Comment: @Lasoloz assign the result of `concat()` to `s`

Comment: `type="text/css"` is wrong for `script` tag , also using `type` is redundant for scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have loaded a JavaScript file as CSS.

```
<script type="text/css" src="mainScript.js"></script>
```

All you should have done is this

```
<script src="mainScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ouch! This was huge mistake! Thanks!

Comment: If that solved your question, do mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Almost! There is also a problem with `concat()`. If it works for me perfectly I will mark. :)

Comment: About `concat()`, you don't need to use that function, just use `+` as mentioned in the comments of your question

Comment: Yes, it was mentioned above in comments